# App shows blank screen after adding @ionic-native/Camera

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to integrate camera into my ionic app, but the issue is app showing blank screen when I add native plugin. Here is how I'm adding native plug-in to my app. Currently I am building this for iOS

> npm install @ionic-native/camera --save

In app.module.ts I'm adding Camera under providers

> import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';
>
> providers: [
>       StatusBar,
>       SplashScreen,
>       Camera,
>       {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
>     ]

If I save any file, live-reload will trigger and showing the error screen, I couldn't able to figure out what is the issue. Can anyone please suggest.

[image]

Console log

```
Error: Debug Failure. 

at typeToString (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:28777:22)
    at reportRelationError (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:34714:34)
    at isRelatedTo (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:34860:21)
    at checkTypeRelatedTo (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:34697:26)
    at checkTypeAssignableTo (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:34398:20)
    at checkVariableLikeDeclaration (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:44884:21)
    at checkPropertyDeclaration (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:43383:13)
    at checkSourceElement (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:46700:28)
    at Object.forEach (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1506:30)
    at checkClassDeclaration (/Users/developermac/Desktop/samples/sample1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45765:16)
```

Comment: Did you run those commands?

    $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
    $ npm install --save @ionic-native/camera

Comment: Yes, I did @HumbertodeCarvalho

Comment: sometimes a simple restart also solves this issue. your declarations are right, meanwhile i am digging more into it..i have used the same and mine is woking fine..leme look for differences, will post the answer if found any